# Reverse word by word efficiency

Tags: java, performance, strings

I have a method that reverse each word in a string. I want to know how I can increase it's performance and memory efficiency. Ideas I had in mind were simply using `char[]` instead of strings being that strings are immutable and each time I concatenate the Strings, I am creating a new String object which is not efficient at all.

Example:

```
hi there cow  --> ih ereht woc
```

Code:

```
public static String reverseWord(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    String strResult = "";
    String strBuffer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            strBuffer = str.charAt(i) + strBuffer;
        }
        else if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            strResult += strBuffer + " ";
            strBuffer = "";
        }
    }
    strResult += strBuffer;
    return strResult;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reversing words in a string](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37364/reversing-words-in-a-string)

Comment: @JamesKhoury This question seeks to reverse the characters within each word. The other question seeks to reverse the words within a sentence.

Comment: @200_success You're right. I had missed that distinction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I literally fell asleep with an answer mostly built.... and now that 200_success and palacsint have covered pretty much my complete answer.

I have to reiterate though that the use of `strBuffer = str.charAt(i) + strBuffer;` will be your worst performance culprit.

Also, (as I learned recently), your code will not handle surrogate Unicode characters well (it will reverse and thus break them). So, I had put together some code which I believe will be much faster than yours, it will handle space and punctuation in a very different way to yours, and it will correctly *not* reverse surrogate pairs in the text.

The reason this code will be faster is because it converts the input String to a single char array, and it does not create any other objects until the end, when it converts the array back to the output String.

```
public class WordRev {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] phrases = { "Hello World!!", " Bilbo Bagginses",
                "Pair\uD800\uDC00Pair" };

        for (String p : phrases) {
            System.out.print(p + " -> ");
            System.out.println(wordReverse(p));
        }
    }

    private static final boolean isWordChar(final char ch) {
        return Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) || Character.isSurrogate(ch);
    }

    private static final String wordReverse(final String p) {
        char[] chars = p.toCharArray();
        int wordstart = 0;
        while (wordstart < chars.length) {
            while (wordstart < chars.length && !isWordChar(chars[wordstart])) {
                wordstart++;
            }
            int wordend = wordstart + 1;
            boolean hasSurrogate = false;
            while (wordend < chars.length && isWordChar(chars[wordend])) {
                if (Character.isSurrogate(chars[wordend])) {
                    hasSurrogate = true;
                }
                wordend++;
            }
            if (wordend - 1 > wordstart) {
                // reverse between.
                int mid = wordstart + (wordend - wordstart - 1) / 2;
                int midoff = (wordend - wordstart - 1) & 1;
                for (int i = mid - wordstart; i >= 0; i--) {
                    char tmp = chars[mid - i];
                    chars[mid - i] = chars[mid + midoff + i];
                    chars[mid + midoff + i] = tmp;
                }
                if (hasSurrogate) {
                    for (int i = wordstart + 1; i < wordend; i++) {
                        if (Character.isLowSurrogate(chars[i - 1])
                                && Character.isHighSurrogate(chars[i])) {
                            char tmp = chars[i];
                            chars[i] = chars[i - 1];
                            chars[i - 1] = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            wordstart = wordend + 1;
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }

}
```

Comment: wow you really went over the top with this and i appreciate it! i thought about surrogate pairs but decided to ignore these cases due to my lack of understanding in concepts.

Answer (score 6):

1. > Ideas I had in mind were simply using char[] instead of strings being that strings are immutable and each time I concatenate the Strings, I am creating a new String object which is not efficient at all.

   Yes, that will be faster. Go ahead and write it :-)
2. Instead of `String`s like `strResult` and `strBuffer` you could use `StringBuilder`s (although using char is probably faster). `StringBuilder` is mutable and would be faster than using `String`s. `StringBuilder` also supports `insert(offset, char)` but also has a `reverse` method.
3. I'd rename  `strResult` to `result` (to avoid Hungarian notation) and `strBuffer` to the more descriptive `currentWord`.
4. > ```
   > if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
   >     ...
   > }
   > else if (str.charAt(i) == ' ') {
   >     ...
   > }
   > ```

   The following is the same, you don't need the second, inverted condition:

   ```
   if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
       ...
   } else {
       ...
   }
   ```
5. You might want to use a more another check for spaces. Currently it handles tabs (`\t`) as normal characters and

   ```
   "hi\tthere\tcow"
   ```

   will be

   ```
   "woc\tereht\tih"
   ```

Here is a slightly improved version with `StringBuilder`s:

```
public static String reverseWord(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
            currentWord.insert(0, str.charAt(i));
        } else {
            result.append(currentWord).append(" ");
            currentWord.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    result.append(currentWord);
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your instincts are correct: the current solution is terribly inefficient.  You'll do approximately one string concatenation for each character in the input string.  Each such concatenation would involve allocating a new string and copying the previous characters.  The running time is O(*m n*), where *m* is the average word length and *n* is the total number of characters.

That said, your algorithm has the advantage of being easy to understand.  For a short string such as "hi there cow", efficiency doesn't really matter.  Sometimes a simple but inefficient algorithm is preferable.

`strBuffer` is an unfortunately confusing name for a `String`, as it suggests that it would be a `StringBuffer`.

Converting your algorithm to use a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` would be a slight improvement, but it would still be inefficient, since `stringBuilder.insert(0, …)` would result in a lot of characters having to be shifted over.  It would still be O(*m n*).

For efficiency, swapping characters within a `char[]` array is definitely the way to go.  To implement that, I suggest defining a helper function

```
/**
 * Reverses the characters of buf, resulting in the characters between
 * start (inclusive) and end (exclusive) get swapped.
 */
private static void reverseChar(char[] buf, int start, int end) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Quick note for OP: `StringBuffer` is for multithread accessing and `StringBuilder` is single thread operation. Synchronization have a good impact on performance, so `StringBuilder` is normally preferred in single thread environment.